# Palloff press stressing anterior deltoids

Tags: abdominals, press

I feel my anterior deltoid is being stressed when I do the Palloff press. Form issue or have I strained something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Palloff press requires isometric contraction of the anterior deltoid, so you should feel it there.